# Program always resorts to "wrong login" despite entering correct info

Tags: python

I do not see any flaws in my code that always resorts to outputting "wrong login!".

```
credentials = {
    "username1": "password1",
    "username2": "password2"
}
while True:
    useroutput = input("Type in your username: ")
    passoutput = input("Type in your password: ")
    if useroutput in credentials.keys() and not(passoutput in credentials.keys()) and passoutput in credentials:
        print("Welcome back "+useroutput+"!")
        break
    else:
        print("Wrong login!")
        continue
```

Comment: The `if` condition makes no sense

Comment: it does perfectly makes sense to me, elaborate why not

Comment: Why do you use both `not(passoutput in credentials.keys())` and `passoutput in credentials`? This contradicts itself.

Answer (score 0):

This checks if username is known, after that checks if the password is assigned to the username

```
credentials = {
    "username1": "password1",
    "username2": "password2"
}
while True:
    useroutput = input("Type in your username: ")
    passoutput = input("Type in your password: ")
    if useroutput in credentials:
        if credentials[useroutput] == passoutput:
            print("Welcome back "+useroutput+"!")
            break

    print("Wrong login!")
```

---

Your condition doesn't work because this part

```
not(passoutput in credentials.keys()) and passoutput in credentials
```

will always be `False`. `passoutput in credentials` will check in the keys. I think you wanted `passoutput in credentials.values()`. Even if this 'would' work, every user could login with every password in the dictionary.